# Using matlabFunction to return symbolic eigenvalues

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

Since matlabFunction can only generate one output argument, how can I use it to create a symbolic expression for the *second* argument of a matlab function?     For example

```
 B = sym('b',[2,2]);
 [Q,Lambda]  = eig(B)
```

will return the eigenvectors and eigenvlaues of B and

Lambda       = eig(B)

returns just the eigenvalues.

```
Q = matlabFunction('eig(B)');
```

returns an anonymous function giving me only the eigenvalues of B but how do I convince matlabFunction to return the first of *two* arguments, and thus return the eigenvectors?    I imagine there's some clever use of the `deal` function but I can't figure it out.    Thanks!

Comment: I assume `eig` is an example, right? Else just type `eig()`, its shorter and clearer

Comment: Not sure if this is the same for the symbolic version, but `eig` with one output argument returns the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered `symfun`,  which solves my problem

```
B = sym('b_%d%d',[2,2]);
[Q,Lambda]  = eig(B);
Qfun        = simplify(symfun(Q,[B(1,1),B(1,2),B(2,1),B(2,2)]));
Lfun        = diag(symfun(Lambda,[B(1,1),B(1,2),B(2,1),B(2,2)]));
```